# I want to browse files and folders in a folder recursively using treeview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for a control or a sample project to browse files and folders of a defined folder recursively with asp.net using treeview.

I dont know if there is such as a free control/sample project like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/hwo_to_create_an_aspnet_ajax_s.html

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks! I came to that site before posting to here but the source code of that site is no longer available. bad luck for me

Comment: @devn: the sourcecode seems to be at the bottom of the page(aspx+codebehind). It looks complete to me.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks Tim, actually I came to a newer post: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/03/building_a_vista_style_folder.htmlbut the source code is not fully I think and it is not downloadable.

Comment: @devn: i get a "Ah Crap ... I couldn't find that page!" with your link. But the older folder-explorer from Matt is very compact and easy to extend. What are you missing and why do you want to download these few lines? I think that you haven't noticed  that he simply uses the [ASP.NET TreeView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in combination with a GridView.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is here:)   http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/03/building_a_vista_style_folder.html

Comment: That is an Vista-Style extension of his original code. So combine both and you are ready. All source code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my article - [Build a File tree explorer with asp.net and jquery](http://riderdesign.com/articles/Build-a-file-tree-explorer-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET.aspx). The original jquery file is no longer available at the source i specified in the article. However i have the jquery file and can make it available.

Edit: I will post code in a bit.

Code is below:

First you'll need server code to access the file system. This is can go inside a code behind file or in the aspx page itself - just delete everything else.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dir As String
    If Request.Form("dir") Is Nothing Or Request.Form("dir").Length <= 0 Then
        dir = "/"
    Else
        dir = Request.Form("dir")
    End If
    Dim di As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(dir))
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    sb.Append("<ul class=""jqueryFileTree"" style=""display: none;"">" & ControlChars.Lf)
    Dim di_child As System.IO.DirectoryInfo
    For Each di_child In di.GetDirectories()
        sb.Append((ControlChars.Tab & "<li class=""directory collapsed""><a href=""#"" rel=""" & dir & di_child.Name & "/"">" & di_child.Name & "</a></li>" & ControlChars.Lf))
    Next di_child
    Dim fi As System.IO.FileInfo
    For Each fi In di.GetFiles()
        Dim ext As String = ""
        If fi.Extension.Length > 1 Then
            ext = fi.Extension.Substring(1).ToLower()
        End If

        sb.Append((ControlChars.Tab & "<li class=""file ext_" & ext & """><a href=""#"" rel=""" & dir & fi.Name & """>" & fi.Name & "</a></li>" & ControlChars.Lf))
    Next fi
    sb.Append("</ul>")
    Response.Write(sb.ToString)
End Sub
```

Next you'll need a page to show the file tree. This page needs to reference the jquery core file and the jquery file tree script. I happen to have a reference to the jquery core file in my master page.

```
<link href="../styles/jqueryFileTree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../scripts/jqueryFileTree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the page that shows the file tree, stick this code. Root is the directory to browse, filetree.aspx has the serve code above. The div becomes the file tree. For the demo i use an iframe to act as the file viewer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        $j('#divFileTree').fileTree({
            root: '/demos/',
            script: 'filetree.aspx',
            expandSpeed: 1000,
            collapseSpeed: 1000,
            multiFolder: false
        }, function (file) {
            alert(file);
            $j('#demoviewer').attr('src', file);
        });
    });


</script>
<div id="divFileTree"></div>
```

Comment: that is a very nice demo. could you please share the source code as well? thanks in advance

Comment: the root is static. I would like to change it from the codebehind, how would it be possible? thanks in advance.

Comment: @devn the root is adjusted in the jquery code in the above page. Also i can email you the jquery file that actually creates the filetree if know your email.

Comment: and when I click on an item, the item is not downloaded? What should I change?

Comment: thanks a lot for your kindness. my email is: trashpopemail@gmail.com, I mean the root path is in jQuery js. is it possible that I can change it from code-behind in C#?

Comment: could you please send me the source of your site?

Comment: could you please send me the source code of you site? I could not get it working with click on the node and download the file. thanks in advance.